# Does Crystal Reports support secure (HTTPS) images

Tags: image, https, crystal-reports

You can enter a URL in a Crystal Reports image *Graphic Location* field to allow Crystal to load it dynamically at runtime. Eg: `http://reports.server.com/logo.png` or `{?_pUrl} & "/logo.png"`

Are you able to use a secure / HTTPS URL? Eg: `https://reports.server.com/logo.png`

---

I've verified outgoing HTTP connections using the TCP/IP tab of Process Explorer, but can't see any outgoing connections when using HTTPS.

My actual report is passing the base URL in via a parameter and works in an HTTP only environment. Also tried using a hard coded HTTPS url, to no avail.

I'm using version 14.0.2.364 RTM hosted in IIS on a 2012 R2 server.

Comment: Try to public the report over https and get the image. You can't take images from a https server if the report is on http (security issues). And i think that crystal report can't get images from https server in fact.

Comment: Not is possible add a Https Graphi Location, the option is use a file server (without https) and include these files in your report.

Comment: I worked around the issue by allowing the image to be downloaded via HTTP (whitelisted the URL; all other access must be via HTTPS).

Comment: Oh, and bonus points to anyone who can point to the first version of Crystal which *does* support loading images via HTTPS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like **Crystal Report 14.0.X** (and earlier) does not support `HTTPS Graphic Location` - [official reference](http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001745884&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031373435383834) from 2013.16.01.

Also checkout [this thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3310943) (from 2013.Feb) where it's mentioned again `Graphic Location formula` over HTTPS is not supported.

Unfortunately it seems the issue is still not resolved.

The common suggested workarounds in the SAP's threads are:

- using HTTP instead of HTTPS
- having the image loaded locally (or from shared location)
- use 3rd party tools to pre-download and store the image from the https to another (local) secure location.

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer because a) the KB ref is more official than forum posts and b) provides some possible work-arounds.

Comment: Still not supported with version 2023

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported.

A SAP employee confirms this in [this thread](https://scn.sap.com/thread/1318144) in the SAP community network (though it relates to an older version):

> You're using the "Graphic Location" formula to specify a URL for the
>   image.  When you return a string with http://, it's working,  but not
>   with https://.
>
> That's currently the behavior in Crystal Reports 2008 Designer, and
>   CR4E CRJ SDK reflects that behavior. [...] it's likely not something that would be implemented in CR4E in
>   the near future.

This also seems to be the case in CR2011 (14.0.x), as stated in [another thread](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3310943):

> if the URL is secured one eg. HTTPS then crystal report wont be able
>   to process the images. Because HTTPS graphic location is not
>   supported.

Comment: Although this answer was more than adequate in citing forum posts by SAP employees, I'm accepting @hovanessyn's answer because it is (slightly) better.

Answer (score 0):

A list of possible work-arounds to this problem:

- Use HTTP rather than HTTPS (you may need to whitelist a particular URL or route if you require all access to be via HTTPS)
- Pass the image via a binary field in your query (either by pushing it in via a dataset or by pulling it from your database)
- Load images from a local filesystem

Answer (score 0):

in Web.config, create a rule in the URL Rewrite, to exclude the file that generates the image, like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="\bBarcode.ashx\b" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" /> <!-- Crystal não suporta imagens https.. Criando exceção para imagens de barcode, utilizadas no crystal -->
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```